# rotating entire page html elements 90 degree counterclockwise

Tags: html, css

I want to rotate entire body 90 degree counterclockwise. Here is what I did:

```css
  body, html {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        background: black;
    }

    .msg {
        color: white;
        font-size: 350%;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 15px gray;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 0;
        direction: ltr; /* lang */
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%
    }
 
 .wrapper{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin:bottom right;
  
  position:absolute;
  top:-100vw;
  
  
  height:100vw;
  width:100vh;
  
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;

  overflow:auto;
 }
```

```html
<body id="body">
<div class='wrapper'>


<div id="caption" class="msg"> Heloooooo</div>
  

</div>

</body>
```

However the result is like the image below and the contents are off located towards the left by almost 50%.  What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: what do you intend to see ? that would really help.

Comment: Hellooo is supposed to appear at the very right side of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **right 0**:

```css
    .rotate90counterclockwise{
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   transform-origin:bottom right;
   position:absolute;
   top:-100vw;
   right:0;
   height:100vw;
   width:100vh;
  }



body, html {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        background: black;
    }

    .msg {
        color: white;
        font-size: 350%;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 15px gray;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 0;
        direction: ltr; /* lang */
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%
    }
```

```html
<body id="body">
<div class='rotate90counterclockwise'>
<div id="caption" class="msg"> Heloooooo</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You rotated the body 90 degrees, anything in the body will also be rotated 90 degrees.

What are you trying to do? Why not just rotate the elements in the body 90 degrees.

---

Thanks for the help. I will look for more clear questions in the future.
Anyways, got it to work on code pen using the method I mentioned above. Code and link below.

---

HTML:

```
<body id="body">
  <div class='wrapper'>

    <div id="caption" class="msg">
      <p>Site Banner</p> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <main></main>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        font-family:Lucida Console;
    }

    .msg {
       float: right; 
    }

.msg > p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-120px, 120px);
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 15px gray;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  direction: ltr; /* lang */
  text-align: right;
}

    .wrapper{
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

main{
  display: block;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222222;
}
```

---

**CodePen**: [Site Banner Upper Right](https://codepen.io/salt-shaker/full/oPwKZX/)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question. Do not put comments in the Answer section. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult what you are trying to do. I think you want to make some all page rotation effect for that. You want to rotate the body to be more easy to control. But it's tricky what you are trying to make. It's more safe to rotate individual elements because, if you rotate the body, it will not be like an image. We talk about coding and you need to change all the page code. Width is ok to control but the height is the tricky one because height is the whole web page.

This is what works for me but maybe just for one text message. When you have more complex things, it will be hard to control it. This is my point.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page</title>
<style>
    body {
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform-origin: bottom right;
        position: absolute;
        top: -75vmax;
        left: -50vmax;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background-color: black;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    h1.red {
        text-align: center;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
</head>

<!-- BODY -->
<body>
    <h1 class="red">TEST TXT!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[SS of how is look on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrDcs.png)

Comment: rotating individual elements is not a good idea as there will be more elements in the screen. Sometimes I want to rate everything 90 degree because or portrait view, sometimes I don't want to rotate at all. So after getting answer to this question I will make a JavaScript wrapper function to do the rotate

Comment: Please be more formal in your language and not treat SO like reddit or other amateur forums. Spell words out completely. Do not use "u" in place of "you" and "want to", not "wanna".

Comment: Sorry, english is not my first language, thanks for corections.